# Errors in java file in Android studio

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.admin.loginpage;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class loginpage extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginpage);
        final EditText etun = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etun);
        final EditText etpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpw);
        final Button btlg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlg);
        final TextView etre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etre);
        etre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void click(View V)
            {
                Intent etreIntent = new Intent(loginpage.this, registerpage.class);
                loginpage.this.startActivity( etreIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Actually this is my java file in android studios to create login,register page.
Error is:

1. Class anonymous class derived from onclicklistener must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method on click(view) in on click listener
2. Method does not override a method from it's supper class.

Comment: Also please make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You got the method name wrong:

```
public void click(View V)
```

it should be:

```
public void onClick(View V)
```

Comment: no change same errors are repeated

Comment: @saisankar did you change exactly what i said?

Comment: yes i did the same

Comment: @saisankar Edit your question and add your changes.